# How to create a DLL library with a standard form layout to use on several forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, dll, standards

I searched a lot of places but with no answer. I want to create a standard window form with a predefined layout on it like: borderless window, a panel with some code to be able to move the window around, close and minimize buttons, etc.

I imagine that this need to be an DLL so any other project that I create on the future could import and use this DLL. Even if I update the layout on DLL all my projects that use it automatically change instead of I having to manually change all windows forms on every project.

If someone could please explain to me step-by-step on how to do this, create, import and use the DLL, I would be very thankfull.

**Edit:** Sorry, it's WinForm. I want to be able to use this standard WinForm layout outside my solution, on other projects. The main solution will only have the standard WinForm layout I created, nothing else. The other projects should be able to insert their components, like buttons, panels, inside the standard WinForm layout. I think I might need to use NuGet package instead of DLL.

Comment: You mean instead of inheriting directly from Windows.Forms, create a new type, in a common assembly, and inherit from that?

Comment: It sounds like you want a common base form (assuming you're talking about WinForms - no tag is present so I have to guess).

Comment: Ignore the fact that you want to do this in another assembly as a first step. Just create a base class that inherits from `Windows.Forms.Form` (assuming this is for Win Forms-please tag your question). Then create a form that inherits from that form. Get it to do what you want. Only once it's working should you move that base class to a new project (which will create a different assembly). Do this all in the same solution. If you want to use this in multiple projects, consider packaging your new assembly in a NuGet package

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do what you need. But first of all you need to do some analysis and design. Find out what layouts and controls are needed, what will change and in what ways. Identify possible modes or patterns to implement by the form. Some drawings on paper will help. Start with a single project to keep things very simple, and when you got it working, go on with a DLL or NuGet package. I'll try to explain a very quick and dirty example with a lot of assumptions.

In short, we will create a form that implements three behaviors or modes. Each mode is composed of two factors:

- GUI.  Controls are added, hidden, changed or moved around its
  containers as needed.
- Code. Event handlers, private methods and all the code to implement what the mode should do.

Every mode should have a single method performing all the needed changes in GUI and code.

An Enumeration should be created (at namespace level) with all needed mode names.

`public enum EditFormMode { Default, CreateClient, EditClient }`

The form Constructor should receive one argument of the enumeration type. And a switch will dispatch execution to the method.

```
{
     public FormEditConfig(EditFormMode mode)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            switch (mode)
            {
             case EditFormMode.Default:
                    CreateDefaultMode();
                    break;
                    
                case EditFormMode.CreateClient:
                    CreateClientMode();
                    break;
                    
                case EditFormMode.EditClient:
                    CreateEditClientMode();
                    break;
            }
        }   
        
        private void CreateDefaultMode()
        { // do default stuff }
        
        private void CreateClientMode()
        { // do create client stuff }
        
        private void CreateEditClientMode()
        { // do edit client stuff }
}
```

And the code to create a form:

```
private FormEditConfig _theForm ;

_theForm = new FormEditConfig(EditFormMode.CreateClient);
```

That's the basic mechanism. How to retrieve data from the form to the calling code is very dependent on the concrete implementation.

Once all modes are implemented and tested, go on and create a new project for a class library, move files, add project references, build the solution and test again.